# Как запустить команду в Rust?

Tags: windows, rust

Не понимаю, как в языке Rust запустить консольную команду:

```
csscomb C:/css.css
```

Пробовал по-разному, но то на то, то на сё ругается… Если что, у меня не получается даже калькулятор запустить:

```
Command::new("%windir%/system32/calc.exe")
    .spawn()
    .expect("ls command failed to start");
```

Выдает одну и ту же ошибку:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'ls command failed to start: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "Не удается найти указанный файл." }', libcore\result.rs:1009:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Comment: Может %windir% не нравится? А если попробовать прописать путь полностью?

Answer (score 2):

`std::Command` берёт просто путь к исполняемому файлу ищет сначала поняв как абсолютный путь, а потом пользуясь `PATH`. Применение переменных среды в пути к файлу, не допускается. Их надо вытаскивать через `std::env`, а потом конкактенировать:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/index.html

Comment: Так мне не нужно принимать аргументы из консоли. Мне нужно чтоб раст имея консольную строку смог ее запустить. Либо я совсем не понял что вы хотели сказать

Comment: Вы хотели изпользовать переменную среды `%windir%`. `std::Command` не сможет её скушать, однако для таких случаев есть `std::env` (это функционал для просмотра среды процесса в целом. То есть, например, через `std::env` можно получить значение `windir` или `PATH`, засунуть из в переменную и получить абсолютный путь к исполняемому файлу)